# SSRS Shrink row if subreport returns nothing - as well as row between SubReports

Tags: reporting-services, null, ssrs-2008, shrink

I have a tablix in SSRS and it has a handful of 'data rows' - two of these rows have sub reports that either return data or not.

How do I get the these rows to shrink if the sub report doesn't return any data. I've shrunk the rows down to very tiny and they do grow as needed but a huge space still exists.

In short how do i say isNothing is returned from the subreport do A B or C ... make row invisible ideally

[image]

We need the rows to shrink if not data is returned. Also if either of the sub report is empty we need the row in between to be invisible as well.

Comment: Have you set the consume container white space proptery to true?

Comment: @Harry i'm sorry for the confusion, i'm not sure what needs to be set i've searched that element and generally understand it. But how do i set the row in between to grow or shrink if the one above it is empty or below it.

Comment: I guess the only way you will know if the subreport has any rows is if you have your subreport datasets in your main report.. even if it is a select TOP 1.. that way you know you either have atleast one row or none.. then you can conditionally hide the blank spaces depending on the countrows of the datasets for your subreport